# MS Access App connect to Azure Sql Db from anywhere

Tags: azure, ms-access, azure-sql-database

I have created an MS Access application that uses Azure SQL Server as the backed Db.   The Access app is designed as much as possible to act like a web app in that nothing is stored locally that couldn't alternatively be saved in a cookie for while the users is working on a specific record.   I have set the main offices IP in the Azure Db firewall and it works great when in the office.

However the desire is to allow the users to use the tool from anywhere, i.e. their home, a hotel, a coffee shop, etc.   I have determined that this cannot be done directly between the local Access app and the Azure SQL Db (on the basis that I can't keep adding new origination IPs on a case by case basis).

Is it possible to create a Azure App Service or App Certification that MS Access can use to authenticate to the Azure close subscription and then through that, have access to the Azure Db?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you have dynamic IP addresses, and this is not necessarily limited to home internet connections - several business broadband providers use dynamic IP addresses too.

If I understand correctly, you need to access your SQL Azure instance from a connection that has a dynamic IP address for debugging or using SQL Management Studio, you will need to create a firewall rule for the entire IP address range your ISP uses. As you can appreciate, this instantly this dilutes the security that comes with using SQL Azure.

If you do want to add the entire IP address range for your ISP, you will need to:

```
1. Go to http://whatsmyip.org to get your current IP address assigned by your ISP.
2. Lookup the IP address range assigned to your ISP by using https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html and entering the IP address from step 1.
3. Create a firewall rule using the start IP address and the end IP address from step 2.
```

I do hope the Azure team will implement other firewall options in the future, such as DNS or MAC address based access rules.

Does this help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure

Or, this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-networkaccess-overview

Finally..

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/link-to-or-import-data-from-an-azure-sql-server-database-88c0cc2c-21dd-46f5-b74a-0db3613f5166

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for the response and apologies for my not getting back to this post. 

I have created a desktop VB application that interacts with the data in the Azure SQL Server.  How do set it up so the users of the desktop app can connect and use the tool from anywhere.  This is WITHOUT opening up the IP range to everything.  I believe it requires Azure active directly, but what else needs to be set up for the app to connect to, authenticate and then connect to the database?